# Character string limit reached early using fread from data.table, CSV lines look fine

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I'm reading a moderately big CSV with `fread` but it errors out with "R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes". `readLines` works fine, however. Pinning down the faulty line (2965), I am not sure what's going on: doesn't seem longer than the next one, for example.

Any thoughts about what is going on and how to overcome this, preferably checking the CSV in advance to avoid an `fread` error?

```r
library(data.table)
options(timeout=10000)

download.file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2010-03.csv",
              destfile = "trip_data.csv", mode = "wb")

dt = fread("trip_data.csv")
#> Error in fread("trip_data.csv"): R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes

lines = readLines("trip_data.csv")

dt2955 = fread("trip_data.csv", nrows = 2955)
#> Warning in fread("trip_data.csv", nrows = 2955): Previous fread() session was
#> not cleaned up properly. Cleaned up ok at the beginning of this fread() call.
dt2956 = fread("trip_data.csv", nrows = 2956)
#> Error in fread("trip_data.csv", nrows = 2956): R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes
lines[2955]
#> [1] "CMT,2010-03-07 18:37:05,2010-03-07 18:41:51,1,1,-73.984211000000002,40.743720000000003,1,0,-73.974515999999994,40.748331,Cre,4.9000000000000004,0,0.5,1.0800000000000001,0,6.4800000000000004"
lines[2956]
#> [1] "CMT,2010-03-07 22:59:01,2010-03-07 23:01:04,1,0.59999999999999998,-73.992887999999994,40.703017000000003,1,0,-73.992887999999994,40.703017000000003,Cre,3.7000000000000002,0.5,0.5,2,0,6.7000000000000002"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When trying to read part of the file (around 100k rows) I got:

```
Warning message:
In fread("trip_data.csv", skip = i * 500, nrows = 500) :
  Stopped early on line 2958. Expected 18 fields but found 19. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<CMT,2010-03-07 03:46:42,2010-03-07 03:58:31,1,3.6000000000000001,-73.961027000000001,40.796674000000003,1,,,-73.937324000000004,40.839283000000002,Cas,10.9,0.5,0.5,0,0,11.9>>
>
```

After removing it I was able to read at least 100 k rows

```
da = data.table(check.names = FALSE)

for (i in 0:200) {
  print(i*500)
  dt = fread("trip_data.csv", skip = i*500, nrows = 500, fill = TRUE)
  da <- rbind(da, dt, use.names = FALSE)
}

str(da)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  101000 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ vendor_id         : chr  "" "CMT" "CMT" "CMT" ...
 $ pickup_datetime   : POSIXct, format: NA "2010-03-22 17:05:03" "2010-03-22 19:24:29" ...
 $ dropoff_datetime  : POSIXct, format: NA "2010-03-22 17:22:51" "2010-03-22 19:40:13" ...
 $ passenger_count   : int  NA 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
[...]
```

> Any thoughts about what is going on and how to overcome this, preferably checking the CSV in advance to avoid an fread error?

Then you can read it line by line, checking length of the list, and binding it to data table.

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Thanks @grzegorz-sapijaszko, this does work for the first 100k lines, but then I bump into another of these rogue 19-length lines. I repeat the process, but then again there's another line. Reading line-by-line by adding the following in your loop is extremely slow (left it all night and didn't complete): if (length(dt)<=18)  da <- rbind(da, dt, use.names = FALSE)

Comment: Just found out that the obvious `read.csv()` works fine... will go with that for now, but could that be an issue worth raising to the data.table team?

Comment: @vinceroni, if you are sure that data in `.csv` is correct, then yes, it's worth to raise the hand and at least discuss the issue. And to be honest, I haven't tested on the whole file, as it was to big even to download it in reasonable time on my connection.